# P as placeholder in generics

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a generic class and used the following code:

```
public class MyClass<P>{

}
```

I am getting a warning "The type parameter P is hiding the type P" . what does that mean?

Comment: It seems that somewhere there is a class named P, which you are 'hiding'

Comment: @Stultuske or there is a type variable called P in the containing class (P is not necessarily a class).

Comment: @AndyTurner the moment it says hiding 'the type' P, my first guess is not a variable, but a class.

Comment: either way, it is a 'Type' declared somewhere, whether it is a passed generic or a class/interface, but I expect there's more code to check than just this.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a class (or inner class or outer type parameter (thanks Andy)) inaptly named `P` on your classpath. To find it, first change to this:

```
public class MyClass {
    P p;
}
```

Then Ctrl-click `P` in your IDE (or whatever shortcut takes you to the declaration of an identifier). If that doesn't work, try auto-import to see which import appears at the top.

Comment: yes you are correct , I had a class as P in my project. Thanks for the input.